# In firebase, does a call to RemoveEventListener guarantee listener will not be triggered?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is for Android/Java implementation of Firebase Database.

If RemoveEventListener is called from the main thread is it guaranteed the listener function will not surface afterwards?  Since the process behind Firebase is most likely multi-threaded, the concern is that a listener callback may be scheduled before removal of the event listener takes place...

```
OnPause()
{
ref.RemoveEventListener(listener);

//safe to destroy objects referenced by listener here???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that you use to call `removeEventListener` doesn't really matter, though it's expected that you're likely using the main thread to do so.  It will do what it says in the API documentation, and the listener will not be invoked again.

Comment: So I can safely delete objects referenced by the listener after removing it?

Comment: Sure, unless you're doing something else strange that you're not showing here.  if you have a very specific concern about what is "unsafe", you should provide more code and explain the context of what you might consider to be unsafe.

Comment: Nothing else strange - objects created and maintained on the main thread.  It's more a question about firebase behavior, akin to does RemoveEventListener and Listener invocation occur on the same thread or at least sync'ed in firebase.  So there is no way an invocation is scheduled on some queue before the listener is removed.  I don't want null pointer exceptions out in the wild...

Comment: Listeners are invoked on the main thread by default.